# How do I stop visitors directly accessing the directories in my website?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I have a (Wordpress powered) website, and Google is indexing some of the sub-directories. How can I stop Apache from showing users the directory listing? I know I can edit .htaccess to password-protect a directory, but I would prefer a 403 / custom redirect if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need this entry in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at your robots.txt rules, and make sure apache is not serving-up directory listings.

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html && http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/5272.htm

Answer (score -2):

Don't know much about Apache but you should do a 404 instead of a 403 if you can because a 403 tells someone that they may have found something interesting.

Comment: You're suggesting that people use an incorrect error code to avoid people thinking they're not allowed to access something that they can't access? What? Moreover, the mediocre security-by-obscurity you're suggesting could also be achieved by correctly returning a 403 where disallowed and not found.